# if/else issues python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

So I'm trying to learn python by making a choose your own adventure game. The problem I'm encountering is that I cannot get the users to actually choose. I've written a bunch of content and I want to have the user choose between going in hole 1 or hole 2. But right now when the user types 1 or 2 though, nothing happens. It just goes to a blank line and presents none of the hole 1/2 content. I think I'm having an issue storing user input and then recalling it but I'm not sure how to solve it. Ideally when the user types 1 or 2 they will be presented with the situations in those holes. I'd like to point out again that I'm a beginner and I'm sure there are better ways or more efficient ways to write this but my primary focus is getting the players into hole 1 or hole 2. I'm using python 3.6 in spyder 3.x.

```
def main():
    print('A giant ship comes crashing down in your swamp and ruins your possum and larvae soup.')
    print('A man emerges from the swamp. Gross he says. Why would anyone live in this shithole swamp?')
    print('Yoda emerges from his hut. I live here. I am Yoda, the talking swamp rat that will teach you how to kill your father.')
    begin = input("Do you want my help? Q=Quit. ")
    if begin.lower() !='q':
        print('Good lets begin') ##!='q': this is how you give someone the option to quit.
    else:
        print('good luck im going to eat some larvae and possum soup')
    userName = input("I have to ask. What is your name? ")
    print('Nice to meet you', userName,'Skywalker')
    print('Okay so first things first, lets get your ship out of my swamp. Great', userName, 'says.')
    print('But I will only do it if you catch me some possums. They are a delicassy here. They are in one of those 2 holes.')
    holeInput = input('Do you want to go into hole one or hole two? type one/two ')
    if holeInput == one: ##why won't this work? 
        print('You enter the hole. It is small and you have to crawl. All of a sudden there is a bright light.')
        print('You see a family of squirrels. Squirrels are not possums.')
        squirrel = input("Do you bring the squirrel to Yoda and hope he does not notice or do you leave? Quit means leave. Q=Quit." )
        if squirrel.lower() !='q':
            print('Congrats! you are now fighting a squirrel. You kill the squirrel in one blow and bring its carcass to Yoda.')
            print('You are a liar! Yoda says. I will not help you. Yoda goes inside and eats some possum and larvae soup.')
            return holeInput  
        else:
            print('You leave the hole to check the other hole.')
            return holeInput
    else:
        return holeInput

    if holeInput == two:
        print('You enter the hole. It is small and you have to crawl. All of a sudden there is a bright light.')
        print('You see a family of possums reading the space bible. One of the possums has glasses and a human face.')
        print('The possum turns to you. I am not a possum he says. My name is George Lucas the possum says. But it could be a lie. He really looks like a possum.')
        lucas = input("Do you listen to the talking possum? Quit means let him live. Q=Quit." )
        if lucas.lower() !='q':
            print('You kill the possum in one blow. You bring his body to Yoda. Wow! thats the biggest possum I have ever seen. You are a good guy and I will help you Yoda says.')
        else:
            print('You leave. Yoda calls you a failure.')
            return holeInput

main()
```

Comment: `1` in source code represents an int. `input` always gives you a string.

Comment: `one` is a variable. `"one"` is a string to compare against. Big difference assuming `one!="one"`

Comment: @user2357112 I changed it to holeInput = int(input('Do you want to go into hole one or hole two? type 1/2 ')) and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should place ' or " around the number or word:

```
if holeInput =='one':
```

or

```
if holeInput =="one":
```

because the user input is returned as a string. so the value is "1" not number 1.

as a side note you can check for multiple correct values (because you told user to input "one/two" they may actually type 'one' or maybe 'two':

```
if holeInput=='1' or holeInput=='one':
```

Comment: Or `if holeInput in { '1', 'one'}`

Comment: @Soroush thanks. I realized I got mixed up with my variables and now I know how to label inputs/variables if I want users to enter numbers/text. Thanks!

Comment: yup good point. actually it should be in brackets `if holeInput in ['1','one']`. the curly brackets {} are for dictionaries, not lists.

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to 
holeInput = int(input('Do you want to go into hole one or hole two? type 1/2 '))
and now it prints the options for hole 1/2. Thanks @user2357112 for the help